# word vba combo box values not displaying although populated

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

I am trying to populate Mail Merge Data fields from excel database and I am successful in pulling it, but when trying to add it in user form combo box, it is not displayed. Although combo box is populated with 3 blank rows. Screenshot attached.
Below code is written in Module1. Do I need to write anything in Combobox1_change() in userform as well?

```
  For Each aField In ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames
      UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem
  Next aField
```

[Userform screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bJOQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told the userform what to add to the combobox. For example:

```
For Each afield In ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames
  UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem afield.Name
Next afield
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! It is displaying values now. 
I am totally new to VBA and learning it on the go. Can you please also help me how these values can be added into array and passed to combobox1_change() in userform. 

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You should post a new question for that, explaining why you need an array (given the items have already been added to the combobox) and what this has to do with the combobox1_change event.